# Windows border problem in Unity and Mate

Tags: 16.04, unity, themes, window, mate

Since I installed Mate the windows on Unity have got this grayish color, as well as the login screen and some menus. The problem is also present in Mate, where some windows don't even have a border. Some windows like the software manager have a completely different border. I'm new to Linux, so I have no idea of what the issue might be. I tried uninstalling Mate, but didn't work.
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Google Chrome oneUnity

[image]

Software Manager on Mate:

[image]